# How to make set of equations appear side by side using empheq package?

Tags: align, empheq

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\sin(A+B)&=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\\
\sin(A-B)&=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A+B)&=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)&=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B
\end{empheq}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)&=2\sin A\cos B\\
\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)&=2\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)&=2\cos A\cos B\\
\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)&=2\sin A\sin B
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

This displays the following sets of formulas:[image]

Here the boxes are placed in vertical order. How would I make them appear side by side?

Comment: `\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\sin(A+B)&=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\\
\sin(A-B)&=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A+B)&=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)&=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B
\end{empheq}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)&=2\sin A\cos B\\
\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)&=2\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)&=2\cos A\cos B\\
\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)&=2\sin A\sin B
\end{empheq}
\end{minipage}`?

Comment: `% \usepackage{empheq}
\newtcbox{\otherbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
enhanced,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=green!10!white,
bottom color=green!10!white,middle color=green!50!yellow},
fuzzy halo=1pt with green,#1}
\begin{empheq}[box=\otherbox]{align}
a&=\sin(z)\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x\, dx
\end{empheq}
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{E} = \otherbox{mc^2}
\end{equation}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly I find `empheq` quite the overkill here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}% or empheq, which loads mathtools, which loads amsmath

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit et amet.
\[
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\sin(A+B)&=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\\
\sin(A-B)&=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A+B)&=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)&=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B
\end{aligned}}
\quad
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)&=2\sin A\cos B\\
\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)&=2\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)&=2\cos A\cos B\\
\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)&=2\sin A\sin B
\end{aligned}}
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit et amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need an awfully small margin to fit that though...

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I propose this coloured version:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=.2in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\colorboxed}[3][white]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5em}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}\colorboxed{IndianRed}{\begin{aligned}
\sin(A+B)&=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\\
\sin(A-B)&=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A+B)&=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)&=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B
\end{aligned}}
\qquad
\colorboxed[LavenderBlush!40]{IndianRed}{\begin{aligned}
\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)&=2\sin A\cos B\\
\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)&=2\cos A\sin B\\
\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)&=2\cos A\cos B\\
\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)&=2\sin A\sin B
\end{aligned}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Unrelated*: Needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`: the latter does it for you. Similar remark for `mathtools` and `empheq`.